# FLASK - How to trigger custom error in Middleware

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python application running with Flask. I use a Middleware to handle various of things. I want to handle here the unexpected error with a try except What can I return in the except part ? I needed my front to retrieve an error code and a message

```
from flask import Flask



class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, middleware_app):
        self.middleware_app = middleware_app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        _request = Request(environ)
        .....
        try:
            return self.middleware_app(environ, start_response)
        except Exception as _e:
            return ??????

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app)
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks